Automatic table numbering with gt package in R when rendering Quarto to Word doc
When rendering a Quarto document to Word and including several tables generated with gt(), something is applying an automatic "Table 1:" to the front of the tab_header(). It is always numbered as Table 1, regardless of the number of tables or if using the gt_group() function. This automatic numbering does not occur when rendering to html (there is no "Table 1:" appended in front of the header).
My main question: is there a way to have it number tables properly (e.g. Table 1, Table 2, etc.)?
Less important to me right now: is there a way to append a prefix or suffix to the numbering (e.g. Table A1, Table A2, etc.)?
---
title: "reprex"
format: docx
editor: visual
---


```{r}
library(gt)

mtcars |> 
  head() |> 
  gt() |> 
  tab_header(title = 'Testing title numbering')

mtcars |> 
  head() |> 
  gt() |> 
  tab_header(title = 'Testing title number 2')

gt_group(
  mtcars |> 
    head() |> 
    gt() |> 
    tab_header(title = 'Testing title number 3'),
  mtcars |> 
    head() |> 
    gt() |> 
    tab_header(title = 'Testing title number 4')
)
```


When I run your code the tables are number like (Table 1:, Table 2: and Table 3:). Which version of Quarto are you using?

Quarto version is 1.4. And gt version is 0.10.1

You could split each table in its own chunk and use tbl-caption instead of tab_header() in the chunk option to produce the table caption, i.e.
---
title: "reprex"
format: docx
---


```{r}
#| label: tbl-example1
#| tbl-cap: "Testing title numbering"

library(gt)

mtcars |> 
  head() |> 
  gt()
```


```{r}
#| label: tbl-example2
#| tbl-cap: "Testing title numbering 2"
mtcars |> 
  head() |> 
  gt()
```


If you want to change the table table prefix you can change them globally in the crossreference e.g. change your yaml to
---
title: "reprex"
format: docx

crossref:
  tbl-prefix: "Tab."
  tbl-title: "A."
---


Interestingly, this only works if you supply the label argument and use the 'tbl-X' syntax for the label. I initially tried it without label and the table captions didn't appear, and similarly tried a label like "tbl1" and "tbl2" and the table captions didn't appear. Only a label like "tbl-1" or "tbl-sex" worked. I was not aware of this requirement to make table captions appear and would be curious to know if that's intended.

Yes it it. Similarily for equations (eq-), figures (fig-) etc.
